# Node.js Express - logging last method entered upon exit

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a clever way to log the last few functions/methods my Node.js program was in when it decided to exit?

you can use

```
 process.on('exit',function(code){
  console.log('exit code:',code);
});
```

but all I have is the exit code - how to get stacktrace?

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit

Comment: What is the benefit of logging last method entered? It could be you got a call to /X which takes 20 seconds (and then fails) but after that you got a call to /Y which took 1 second and succeeded... in this case you will log /Y while /X actually crashed the system.

Answer (score 1):

Dump a stacktrace:

```
process.on('exit',function(code) { 
    var stack = new Error().stack
    console.log( stack )
});
```

Comment: @self (cool handle by the way): why? Did I misunderstand the q?

Comment: @deitch because the stack on the Error will not contain the function it came from. Try it.